# org.hibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a null or transient value : exception only with @Scheduled

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

I am coding for a JPA project (hibernate with spring).

The problem am facing is when I execute the below `interestCalculation()` method with `@Scheduled` annotation I am getting exception:

```
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: not-null property references a null or transient value : com.mad.app.domain.DemandLedgerMap.demandLedger; nested exception is org.hibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a null or transient value : com.mad.app.domain.DemandLedgerMap.demandLedger
```

After the `for` loop in `quartsTestdDisplay()` is completely executed. But, when I execute same method without scheduled data is persisting/updating after `for` loop is executed.
Only when the method triggered from `@Scheduled` it is throwing exception.

Below is my code, one is deligate layer class another one is service layer class.
In delegate layer I have used `@Scheduled` for schedule trigger `interestCalculation()`.

```
  @Controller
  public class DcbDailyBalanceDelegate {

@Autowired
private DcbDailyBalanceService dcbDailyBalanceService;
/**
 * El name.
 */
public static final String EL_NAME = "#{dcbDailyBalanceDelegate}";

@Transactional
@Scheduled(cron="0 37 11 ? * THU")
public void interestCalculation()
{
    //dcbDailyBalanceService.dcbBalanceToDcbDailybalance();
    dcbDailyBalanceService.quartsTestdDisplay();
}

}

@Transactional
public void quartsTestToUpdate()
{

    for (int i = 0; i < 3000; i++) {

        DcbDailyBalance dcbDailyBalance=new DcbDailyBalance();

        DemandLedgerMap  demandLedgerMap=new DemandLedgerMap();

        DledgerApplicableMap dledgerApplicableMap=new DledgerApplicableMap();

        demandLedgerMap.setDldgrMapId(1);
        dledgerApplicableMap.setDlamapId(1);

        dcbDailyBalance.setDcbbalAmount(1000+i);
        dcbDailyBalance.setDcbbalDataSource((byte) 0);
        dcbDailyBalance.setDcbbalDate(1409120385);
        dcbDailyBalance.setDcbbalIntrstAmount(100+i);
        dcbDailyBalance.setDcbbalLastupdated(1409120385);
        dcbDailyBalance.setDemandLedgerMap(demandLedgerMap);
        dcbDailyBalance.setDledgerApplicableMap(dledgerApplicableMap);

        DcbDailyBalance dailyBalance=dailyBalanceDao.update(dcbDailyBalance);

     }
    }
```

Here's the exception:

```
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: not-null property references a null or transient value : com.mad.app.domain.DemandLedgerMap.demandLedger; nested exception is org.hibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a null or transient value : com.mad.app.domain.DemandLedgerMap.demandLedger
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:206) ~[spring-orm-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:154) ~[spring-orm-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:519) ~[spring-orm-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:757) ~[spring-tx-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:726) ~[spring-tx-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:478) ~[spring-tx-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:272) ~[spring-tx-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95) ~[spring-tx-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:646) ~[spring-aop-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    at com.mad.app.controller.dcb.DcbDailyBalanceDelegate$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$7abb9f11.interestCalculation(<generated>) ~[spring-core-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_55]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_55]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_55]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_55]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:65) ~[spring-context-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54) ~[spring-context-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:81) [spring-context-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_55]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_55]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_55]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_55]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_55]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_55]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_55]


Caused by: org.hibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a null or transient value : com.mad.app.domain.DemandLedgerMap.demandLedger
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Nullability.checkNullability(Nullability.java:106) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.1.Final.jar:4.3.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.scheduleUpdate(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:309) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.1.Final.jar:4.3.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.onFlushEntity(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:160) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.1.Final.jar:4.3.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEntities(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:231) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.1.Final.jar:4.3.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEverythingToExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:102) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.1.Final.jar:4.3.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:55) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.1.Final.jar:4.3.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1218) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.1.Final.jar:4.3.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:421) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.1.Final.jar:4.3.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.beforeTransactionCommit(JdbcTransaction.java:101) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.1.Final.jar:4.3.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:177) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.1.Final.jar:4.3.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:77) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.1.Final.jar:4.3.1.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:515) ~[spring-orm-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    ... 22 common frames omitted
```

Below is DcbDailyBalance class

```
    import java.io.Serializable;

    import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
    import javax.persistence.Column;
    import javax.persistence.Entity;
    import javax.persistence.FetchType;
    import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
    import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
    import javax.persistence.Id;
    import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
    import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
    import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
    import javax.persistence.Table;

    import com.mad.app.common.domain.BusinessEntity;


/**
 * The persistent class for the dcb_daily_balances database table.
 * 
 */
@Entity
@Table(name="dcb_daily_balances")
@NamedQuery(name="DcbDailyBalance.findAll", query="SELECT d FROM DcbDailyBalance d")
public class DcbDailyBalance extends BusinessEntity  implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private int dcbbalId;
    private double dcbbalAmount;
    private byte dcbbalDataSource;
    private int dcbbalDate;
    private int dcbbalLastupdated;
    private byte dcbbalRowStatus;
    private double dcbbalIntrstAmount;
    private DemandLedgerMap demandLedgerMap;
    private DledgerApplicableMap dledgerApplicableMap;


    public DcbDailyBalance() {
    }


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="DCBBAL_ID")
    public int getDcbbalId() {
        return this.dcbbalId;
    }

    public void setDcbbalId(int dcbbalId) {
        this.dcbbalId = dcbbalId;
    }

    @Column(name="DCBBAL_AMOUNT")
    public double getDcbbalAmount() {
        return this.dcbbalAmount;
    }

    public void setDcbbalAmount(double dcbbalAmount) {
        this.dcbbalAmount = dcbbalAmount;
    }


    @Column(name="DCBBAL_DATA_SOURCE")
    public byte getDcbbalDataSource() {
        return this.dcbbalDataSource;
    }

    public void setDcbbalDataSource(byte dcbbalDataSource) {
        this.dcbbalDataSource = dcbbalDataSource;
    }


    @Column(name="DCBBAL_DATE")
    public int getDcbbalDate() {
        return this.dcbbalDate;
    }

    public void setDcbbalDate(int dcbbalDate) {
        this.dcbbalDate = dcbbalDate;
    }


    @Column(name="DCBBAL_LASTUPDATED")
    public int getDcbbalLastupdated() {
        return this.dcbbalLastupdated;
    }

    public void setDcbbalLastupdated(int dcbbalLastupdated) {
        this.dcbbalLastupdated = dcbbalLastupdated;
    }


    @Column(name="DCBBAL_ROW_STATUS")
    public byte getDcbbalRowStatus() {
        return this.dcbbalRowStatus;
    }

    public void setDcbbalRowStatus(byte dcbbalRowStatus) {
        this.dcbbalRowStatus = dcbbalRowStatus;
    }

    @Column(name="DCBBAL_INTRST_AMOUNT")
    public double getDcbbalIntrstAmount() {
        return this.dcbbalIntrstAmount;
    }

    public void setDcbbalIntrstAmount(double dcbbalIntrstAmount) {
        this.dcbbalIntrstAmount = dcbbalIntrstAmount;
    }


    //bi-directional many-to-one association to DemandLedgerMap
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
    @JoinColumn(name="DCBBAL_DLDGR_MAP_ID")
    public DemandLedgerMap getDemandLedgerMap() {
        return this.demandLedgerMap;
    }

    public void setDemandLedgerMap(DemandLedgerMap demandLedgerMap) {
        this.demandLedgerMap = demandLedgerMap;
    }


    //bi-directional many-to-one association to DledgerApplicableMap
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
    @JoinColumn(name="DCBBAL_DLAMAP_ID")
    public DledgerApplicableMap getDledgerApplicableMap() {
        return this.dledgerApplicableMap;
    }

    public void setDledgerApplicableMap(DledgerApplicableMap dledgerApplicableMap) {
        this.dledgerApplicableMap = dledgerApplicableMap;
    }

}
```

Below is DemandLedgerMap class

```
    import java.io.Serializable;
    import java.util.List;

    import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
    import javax.persistence.Column;
    import javax.persistence.Entity;
    import javax.persistence.FetchType;
    import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
    import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
    import javax.persistence.Id;
    import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
    import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
    import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
    import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
    import javax.persistence.Table;

    import org.hibernate.annotations.Cascade;

    import com.mad.app.common.domain.BusinessEntity;


    /**
     * The persistent class for the demand_ledger_map database table.
     * 
     */
    @Entity
    @Table(name="demand_ledger_map")
    @NamedQuery(name="DemandLedgerMap.findAll", query="SELECT d FROM DemandLedgerMap d")
    public class DemandLedgerMap extends BusinessEntity implements Serializable {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        private int dldgrMapId;
        private byte dldgrMapRowStatus;
        private List<DcbLine> dcbLines;
        private DemandLedger demandLedger;
        private UnitAllocation unitAllocation;
        private List<DcbDailyBalance> dcbDailyBalances;

        public DemandLedgerMap() {
        }


        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
        @Column(name="DLDGR_MAP_ID", unique=true, nullable=false, columnDefinition = "TINYINT")
        public int getDldgrMapId() {
            return this.dldgrMapId;
        }

        public void setDldgrMapId(int dldgrMapId) {
            this.dldgrMapId = dldgrMapId;
        }


        @Column(name="DLDGR_MAP_ROW_STATUS", nullable=false)
        public byte getDldgrMapRowStatus() {
            return this.dldgrMapRowStatus;
        }

        public void setDldgrMapRowStatus(byte dldgrMapRowStatus) {
            this.dldgrMapRowStatus = dldgrMapRowStatus;
        }


        //bi-directional many-to-one association to DcbLine
        @OneToMany(mappedBy="demandLedgerMap")
        public List<DcbLine> getDcbLines() {
            return this.dcbLines;
        }

        public void setDcbLines(List<DcbLine> dcbLines) {
            this.dcbLines = dcbLines;
        }

        public DcbLine addDcbLine(DcbLine dcbLine) {
            getDcbLines().add(dcbLine);
            dcbLine.setDemandLedgerMap(this);

            return dcbLine;
        }

        public DcbLine removeDcbLine(DcbLine dcbLine) {
            getDcbLines().remove(dcbLine);
            dcbLine.setDemandLedgerMap(null);

            return dcbLine;
        }


        //bi-directional many-to-one association to DemandLedger
        @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
        @JoinColumn(name="DLDGR_MAP_DLDGR_ID", nullable=false)
        public DemandLedger getDemandLedger() {
            return this.demandLedger;
        }

        public void setDemandLedger(DemandLedger demandLedger) {
            this.demandLedger = demandLedger;
        }


        //bi-directional many-to-one association to UnitAllocation
        @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
        @JoinColumn(name="DLDGR_MAP_UALLOC_ID", nullable=false)
        public UnitAllocation getUnitAllocation() {
            return this.unitAllocation;
        }

        public void setUnitAllocation(UnitAllocation unitAllocation) {
            this.unitAllocation = unitAllocation;
        }

        //bi-directional many-to-one association to DcbDailyBalance
            @OneToMany(mappedBy="demandLedgerMap")
            @Cascade(org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL)
            public List<DcbDailyBalance> getDcbDailyBalances() {
                return this.dcbDailyBalances;
            }

            public void setDcbDailyBalances(List<DcbDailyBalance> dcbDailyBalances) {
                this.dcbDailyBalances = dcbDailyBalances;
            }

            public DcbDailyBalance addDcbDailyBalance(DcbDailyBalance dcbDailyBalance) {
                getDcbDailyBalances().add(dcbDailyBalance);
                dcbDailyBalance.setDemandLedgerMap(this);

                return dcbDailyBalance;
            }

            public DcbDailyBalance removeDcbDailyBalance(DcbDailyBalance dcbDailyBalance) {
                getDcbDailyBalances().remove(dcbDailyBalance);
                dcbDailyBalance.setDemandLedgerMap(null);

                return dcbDailyBalance;
            }

    }
```

please anyone help me to resolve this problem

Comment: Post your DcbDailyBalance and DemandLedgerMap class.

Comment: @ Vimal Bera DcbDailyBalance and DemandLedgerMap class posted.. please help me..

Comment: did you try @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)

Answer (score 0):

> PropertyValueException: not-null property references a null or
>   transient value : com.kssidc.app.domain.DemandLedgerMap.demandLedger

This clearly states that in the class `DemandLedgerMap` you are trying to persist demandLedger, which is a non-nullable field.
So when you are using `dcbDailyBalanceService.quartsTestdDisplay();` you are not providing the value for this.

Thus while persisting/updating this it will look for a value for demandLedger and it is getting a null value thus it throws an exception.

Comment: thank you Ekansh.. ya you are right am not providing the value for DemandLedgerMap.demandLedger object but here the  problem is am getting exception only when the dcbDailyBalanceService.quartsTestdDisplay(); method executed from '@Scheduled' scheduler, when same method executed from jsf actionlistner data is persisting to db without throwing any exception. am using entitymanager.merge(entity) to save data.

Comment: please just double check that `entitymanager.merge(entity)` is updating anything or not. I hope it might not be doing anything. If it is not then try **em.getTransaction().begin();
    em.merge(entity);
    em.getTransaction().commit();** Check if you are getting an exception in either case and if either of the two successfully does what they are intended to do .

Comment: No nothing is updating to DB the for loop is completely executes i wont get any exception when entities are flushing at that time am getting nullability check exception.

Comment: I am sure when you will do the save/update operation inside the transaction you will get an exception. The reason will be, hibernate first query is to save the entity, that is done successfully. Then hibernate queries to save the many-many relation. But if you do not do  it as specified in the above comment then hibernate will skip this query. As a result u will not get exception but your record will not be saved. When you view it, you will get an exception since the value is null.

Comment: i tried em.getTransaction().begin(); em.merge(entity); em.getTransaction().commit(); but am getting exception on line em.getTransaction().begin(); exception is  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not allowed to create transaction on shared EntityManager - use Spring transactions or EJB CMT instead

Comment: make sure you either have `@Transactional` annotation or the TransactionManager. YOu can use only one of them at a time.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to persist `DcbDailyBalance` class which has `DemandLedgerMap` class. But in `DemandLedgerMap`, `dldgrMapRowStatus` and `demandLedger` columns are set to `nullable=false` and you are not passing value for this.

That's why when you try to persist `DcbDailyBalance`, it is throwing exception. Hope it's clear.

Comment: Here demandledger is also one entity DemandLedgerMAp has many-to-one mapping with DemandLedger. I wan to save data only in DcbDailyBalnce so am setting all values that will persit in DcbDailyBalnce. demandLedger is DemandLedger type variable in DemandLedgerMap entity i don hav any data for it or user will not enter any data in screen(browser) for demandLedger, only when saving data to DemandLedgerMap i will set data to demandLedger.

Comment: DcbDailyBalance variables (private int dcbbalId;
 private double dcbbalAmount;
 private byte dcbbalDataSource;
 private int dcbbalDate;
 private int dcbbalLastupdated;
 private byte dcbbalRowStatus;
 private double dcbbalIntrstAmount;
 private DemandLedgerMap demandLedgerMap;
 private DledgerApplicableMap dledgerApplicableMap;)

Comment: Then don't set DemandLedgerMAp in DcbDailyBalance object. It will work fine

Answer (score 0):

You need to add you "dcbDailyBalance" to demandLedgerMap list and then insert demandLedgerMap. When you try to update dcbDailyBalance, it'll try to save dcbDailyBalance and then "cascade" and save demandLedgerMap, therefore demandLedgerMap "is null or transient value". Saving demandLedgerMap will create and demandLedgerMap.id and it won't be transient anymore, then you can save dcbDailyBalance. Try this:

```
demandLedgerMap.addaddDcbDailyBalance(dcbDailyBalance);
demandLedgerMapDAO.update(dailyBalanceDao);
```